# PWA url is not accessible from my machine

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio, venia

I have configured the PWA on local by following https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/ and PWA URL is generated successfully and working fine on my local machine. When I followed the same steps on server then it generate url for PWA successfully but when I try to access this URL from my machine’s browser then it shows 404 (not working). It seems this url can be access only on the machine on which pwa is configured i.e. URL is not public.
Do we need to configure or follow some additional steps?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Port like 10000 should be publicly accessible . Make it publicly accessible on server.
I hope it will help you